# Position predicates with xmerl_xpath in Erlang

Tags: xpath, erlang

I'm trying to use [xmerl_xpath](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/xmerl_xpath.html) to query a parsed XML document in Erlang, but I can't get the position predicates to work. Instead of returning the nth child element, I get the nth element of everything selected so far.

Sample code, where I'd like to extract the values 11 and 21 (the "first column"):

```
{XML,_} = xmerl_scan:string(
    "<table>" ++
        "<row><el>11</el><el>12</el></row>" ++
        "<row><el>21</el><el>22</el></row>" ++
    "</table>" ).

4 = length(xmerl_xpath:string( "//table/row/el", XML )). % OK
1 = length(xmerl_xpath:string( "(//table/row/el)[1]", XML )). % OK
1 = length(xmerl_xpath:string( "//table/row/el[1]", XML )). % Why not 2?
```

Is the result of the last query expected? What's the proper way, in the general case, to extract the nth child using xmerl_path?

(What I'm really trying to do is to parse HTML using mochiweb_html and query it using [mochiweb_xpath](https://github.com/retnuh/mochiweb_xpath), but the latter is essentially a wrapper around xmerl_xpath.)

Comment: i would use erlsom library for anything to do with XML in erlang (   http://erlsom.sourceforge.net/ ) . its much more stable, more side effect free and the documentation is clear. xmerl is really tricky

Comment: Thanks, but the documentation of erlsom suggests using the xpath functions that come with xmerl... (My problem is querying, not parsing.)

Comment: Sad to report that this bug is still present in the latest Erlang/OTP in 2023.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Erlang, but the third XPath should indeed extract the first column - the two nodes `<el>11</el>` and `<el>21</el>` - I create a simple test XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:for-each select="//table/row/el[1]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

that applied to

```
<table>
  <row>
    <el>11</el>
    <el>12</el>
  </row>
  <row>
    <el>21</el>
    <el>22</el>
  </row>
</table>
```

produces:

```
<root>
  <el>11</el>
  <el>21</el>
</root>
```

If this is not what you are getting I suspect that the library you are using is buggy.

Comment: I suppose you're right: it's probably a bug. How very depressing.